# getting 500 internal server error in different environment

Tags: web-services, http-status-code-500

In one environment I am sending the web service request then I am getting 200 status. If I send the same web service request from another environment, then I am getting status like 500 internal server error. 
May i know the reasons for getting status like that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check Authentication and Authorization that you have access for another environment or not